# Only show 3 list-elements of "News" on Homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this website where the site "news" has the following code:

```
<ul id="newstoggle"><?php include("content/_news.php"); ?></ul>
```

And the module "_news.php" includes all the list-elements like this:

```
<li class="newstoggle">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
...
</li>

<li class="newstoggle">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
...
</li>

...
```

Now the customer wants the 3 most recent news entries on his home page.

I've already tried it with this JS code (which i also found on stackoverflow), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if ($("body").hasClass("home")) {
$(".newstoggle").slice(0, 3).each(function(index) {
    // Do whatever you want to the first three elements
 }
}
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help as unfortunately I'm quite a beginner in the field of JS and jQuery.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use css, eg `li.newstoggle { display:none } li.newstoggle:nth-child(-n+3) { display:block; }`

Comment: There's a few existing answers, try searching for [css first n](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+first+n)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, I didn't think it would be so easy to solve my problem and that I might have been able to do it myself...

Comment: `$(".newstoggle:gt(3)").hide()` or hide all and do `$(".newstoggle:lt(4)").show()`